# How to fix this gRPC installation problem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, grpc

Im following these steps to install gRPC on my freshly launched AWS EC2 Instance:

```
https://jitpaul.blog/2018/04/18/grpc-on-aws/
```

When I try to execute this line:

```
sudo yum install libgflags-dev libgtest-dev
```

I get this error:

[image: error message]

I don't want to mess up anything, please help.

Comment: It's better to copy-paste the error message to your question than to post an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
sudo yum install gflags-dev
sudo yum install gtest-dev
```

That should install libgflags-dev and libgtest-dev.

Comment: @VonC didnt help.

Comment: @EkaterinaMakesimova OK. That was from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-updates.html